# Corda with HCS pluggable consensus

Tags: corda, hashgraph

I am trying to understand the applicability of pluggable consensus in corda.

For example, the consensus service from hedera hashgraph can be plugged into corda,technically. But I am not clear why it is needed?

Can anyone help me in understanding with an appropriate business use case?

Answer (score 0):

Corda is an incredibly powerful toolkit for building business networks in a distributed manner. One assumption of Corda today is that it depends on either a centralized notary, or the need to configure a network of notaries, in order to provide uniqueness consensus of the Corda transactions.

The Hedera Consensus Service addresses this dependency. Rather than building a cluster of notaries, or trusting a single notary, transaction hashes can be sent to the Hedera Consensus Service which provides a consensus timestamp of the message by the globally distributed Hedera Mainnet. Any notary or member of the Corda network can independently verify the timestamp. This can provide a more decentralized and resilient infrastructure, as well as reduce the operating burden and cost of configuring the Corda network.

More information can be found on the corda notary here: https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-hcs-corda-demo